# Using switch statement with enumeration

Tags: java, enums

I found following from form this site. I added some code to get user input. But there is exception called NullPointerExecption at begining of switch statement.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        double gpa;
        System.out.println("Enter your GPA: ");
        gpa = input.nextDouble();
        Grade grade = Grade.getGradeFromGPA(gpa);



        switch (grade) {
            case FIRST_CLASS:   System.out.println("First class Hons"); break;
            case TWO_ONE:       System.out.println("upper Second class Hons"); break;
            case TWO_TWO:       System.out.println("Lower Second class Hons"); break;
            case PASS:          System.out.println("Pass"); break;
            case FAIL:          System.out.println("Fail"); break;
            default:            System.out.println("Invalied GPA");
        }
    }

    private enum Grade {
        FIRST_CLASS(3.5, 4),
        TWO_ONE(3, 3.49),
        TWO_TWO(2.5, 2.99),
        PASS(2.49, 2),
        FAIL(0, 1.99);

        private final double minGPA;
        private final double maxGPA;

        Grade(final double minGPA, final double maxGPA) {
            this.minGPA = minGPA;
            this.maxGPA = maxGPA;
        }

        static Grade getGradeFromGPA(double gpa) {
            for (Grade grade : Grade.values()) {
                if (grade.maxGPA >= gpa && grade.minGPA <= gpa) {
                    return grade;
                }
            }
            //invalid GPA
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I think it doesn't return anything by `getGradeFromGPA()` method.

Comment: What GPA do you enter?

Comment: I didn't get it..! double value?

Comment: @cmit, not all reals can be represented as doubles. And since you have both upper and lower limits you may get null for values within 4-0 (such as if you type 2.49 for instance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think it doesn't return anything by getGradeFromGPA() method.

That's correct. If you enter for instance `55` the `getGradeFromGPA` will return `null`.

Note that some doubles can't be represented accurately, so if you enter `2.49` for instance, this will also yield `null`.

(Also, you seem to have swapped the arguments on `PASS` enum.)

> How to fix this?

As for the issues with `double`, I'd suggest you do:

```
private enum Grade {
    FIRST_CLASS(3.5),
    TWO_ONE(3),
    TWO_TWO(2.5),
    PASS(2),
    FAIL(0);

    private final double minGPA;

    Grade(final double minGPA) {
        this.minGPA = minGPA;
    }

    static Grade getGradeFromGPA(double gpa) {
        for (Grade grade : Grade.values()) {
            if (gpa > grade.minGPA)
                return grade;
        }
        //invalid GPA
        return null;
    }
}
```

Still, the case when you enter, say, `55` needs to be dealt with. Best way is probably to use exceptions:

```
static Grade getGradeFromGPA(double gpa) {
    for (Grade grade : Grade.values()) {
        if (gpa > grade.minGPA)
            return grade;
    }
    //invalid GPA
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();  // <----------
}
```

and

```
try {
    Grade grade = Grade.getGradeFromGPA(gpa);
    switch (grade) {
        case FIRST_CLASS:   System.out.println("First class Hons"); break;
        case TWO_ONE:       System.out.println("upper Second class Hons"); break;
        case TWO_TWO:       System.out.println("Lower Second class Hons"); break;
        case PASS:          System.out.println("Pass"); break;
        case FAIL:          System.out.println("Fail"); break;
    }
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    System.out.println("Invalied GPA");
}
```

Comment: No I entered valued between 4-0 like 2.4. It didn't work but if I entered 3.1 like value it works as expected. logical error.......

Comment: Yeah thanks a lot I fix it. Need to change "if (gpa > grade.minGPA)" to "if(gpa>=minGPA)" . All brains in finger tips  . Great !

Answer (score 1):

If you enter an invalid GPA, `Grade.getGradeFromGPA(gpa)` will return `null`, and can't be used in a `switch` statement.

You could handle it explicitly if you wish:

```
Grade grade = Grade.getGradeFromGPA(gpa);

if (grade == null) {
    System.out.println("Invalid GPA");
}
else {
    switch (grade) {
        case FIRST_CLASS:   System.out.println("First class Hons"); break;
        case TWO_ONE:       System.out.println("upper Second class Hons"); break;
        case TWO_TWO:       System.out.println("Lower Second class Hons"); break;
        case PASS:          System.out.println("Pass"); break;
        case FAIL:          System.out.println("Fail"); break;
    }
}
```